# React Native - Function not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I have this little code snippet:

```
var okidok = parseString(myXml, (err, result) => {
  console.log(result.rss.channel[0].item); //Gives the output that I want.
  return result.rss.channel[0].item;
});

console.log(okidok); //Output is rubbish.
```

Why okidok is not assigned value which return from `parseString`. All of this is happening inside an async function.

If anyone can enlighten me, I would be very greatful!

Comment: I believe the output is never returned but passed to the callback even when not using ``async``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is happening inside an ES7 async function you can wait `parseString` function to resolve doing this :

First you'll need to promisify `parseString` (in case it's not already *thenable*) :

```
function parseStringPromise(text){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      parseString(text, (err, result) => {
         if(err) return reject(err);
         return resolve(data);
      });
   });
}
```

Then you can `await` for this function to get the result outside of its scope in an `async function` :

```
async function parseXml(myXml) {
   const result = await parseStringPromise(myXml);
   var okidok = result.rss.channel[0].item;
}
```

Note that you can add a `try/catch` statement to handle errors in async function.

**Edit :** I forgot to tell you *why*.

You don't have the same result because the `parseString` function is a *Node style callback ("nodeback")* asynchronous function. Asynchronous function means that you have to wait for it to resolve in order to get the result. There's some different *types* of asynchronous functions, the main 2 are the callback based (like your `parseString`) and the promises (resolvable by `.then(fn)` or `await` in `async functions`).

In order to use `await` on a function this function needs to return a promise (that's why we *promisified* `parseString`)

Here's a promise tutorial easier to understand : https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Comment: I edited my answer with some informations about 'why' and a link that explains promises